# Checking if checkbox is checked is always true even when ID isn't on page

Tags: php, jquery

All,
I have the following code:

```
if($('#future_date_post:checked')){
    alert('it is open');
    $('#future_date_post_select').show();
}
```

I then have the following PHP code on my page:

```
if($action=="edit" && $post_to_edit['post_status'] == "future"){
    echo '<input type="checkbox" id="future_date_post" name="future_date_post" value="yes" checked> Click this box to schedule this post for a future date<br>';
}else{
    echo '<input type="checkbox" id="future_date_post" name="future_date_post" value="yes"> Click this box to schedule this post for a future date<br>';
}
```

My jQuery is always saying my checkbox has a checked value even though it doesn't 99% of the time. I'm also getting the alert on every page even though the other pages don't even have the ID on it. Why is it doing that?

Comment: use `$('#future_date_post:checked').length` in condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [several ways](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2013/02/jquery-test-check-if-checkbox-checked.html) to do it.  To get a boolean value I would check it like this:

```
if($('#future_date_post').is(':checked')){
    alert('it is open');
    $('#future_date_post_select').show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `if` statement is incorrect. jQuery selections will always return a jQuery object (albeit one with a length of zero), even if there are no matching selectors on the page. In JavaScript, all objects evaluate to `true`, except for `null`, `undefined`, `NaN`, `""`, or `0`.

Since zero is "falsey" in javascript, just check the length of the returned object:

```
if($('#future_date_post:checked').length){
    alert('it is open');
    $('#future_date_post_select').show();
}
```